PowerBI: Conditional Formatting on a Measure
Essentially, I need to create a table that lists out my product id’s based on categories identical to this video https://youtu.be/WSnB5y2JXv8?si=WQHOT__uKcEWAjTQ. But my issue is I have another color field that I would like to conditionally format each cell by. When I try to basic conditional formatting on those measure values it takes the first value in a column and colors the entire column with that color.
I tried to do basic conditional formatting and it lead to the error above where columns were all the same color. The only half baked solution I got was to add a color column (since it’s only a few colors) and it colored them correctly. But I want there to be one column and multiple colors in each one to eliminate the need for scrolling across the page.
